# How git store commits - how changes are saved?

Tags: git

When git makes commit it reflected in `.git` directory only changed files or all project files?

Why `git gc` not preceded after every commit?
For what this command was created?

Comment: Start with https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 0):

Every version of every file is stored in the `.git` directory. So let's say you have three files in there: A1, B1, and C1. Then you do a commit that changes A1 to A2. After that, `.git` will contain A1, B1, C1, and A2. So all project files are indeed in the `.git` directory, but only one was added, because only one was changed.

Two reasons I can think of offhand why `git gc` is not run after every commit is a) it takes time and b) it gets rids of files that you may want to retrieve later. You can think of `git gc` as being like emptying your recycle bin on Windows; it prevents you from easily "undeleting" files later on.

Comment: "it prevents you from easily "undeleting" files later on." Can you, please, explain it? git gc brokes the history?

Comment: It does not break the history, no; if you have a file in your history, it is always retrievable. What I was referring to is when you have a commit that you undo with `git reset`, `git commit --amend`, or something similar. You probably do not need to worry about it.

Comment: ok, and if we push commit from your example - only changed file will be pushed?

Comment: Yup, exactly, because the server already has the original files.

Comment: there is yet one opinion http://godd2.blogspot.com/2015/05/git-commits-are-not-transactions.html?m=1

Comment: "Each Git commit contains a compressed snapshot of your entire working directory*.  To be more precise, it contains a reference to a list of compressed files.  Each of those compressed files are what you "git add"ed in the last iteration including the files that you did not change."